# CSS Flexbox - justify-content: flex-end and hidden sidebar

Tags: css, flexbox

i've got a simple question regarding flexbox.

i've got a sidebar that can be toggled with a button. if the toggle sets it to be visible, it slides in from the right. (width 0 --> width 400).

the problem is that some buttons which are aligned to the right via 'justify-content: flex-end' are still visible at the right side, even is the width of the "container" (sidebar) is zero.

the problem occurs if i use:

```
justify-content: flex-end
```

if i leave that out, the buttons disappear as they are supposed to.

here is a simple codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvqroJ

i don't want to "hack around" to make those buttons disappear, so i'm wondering if i'm doing something wrong here and if that common scenario can be solved with a pure flexbox solution.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `justify-content: flex-end` force the element size.
You can fix it in 2 ways:

**First method:** Add `overflow: hidden` in your .sidebar

```
.sidebar {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  height:100%;
  transition: all 4s ease;
}
```

**Second method:** inside .hidden, set the width like in .sidebar (in your case 400px) and set the right position like the width size, but in negative, so -400px

```
.hidden {
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 0px;
  right: -400px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 4s ease;
}
```

The second method is better, because you are moving the element without compress his width and his child elements

---

**A little trick**

You can clean your `.hidden` class with just one property, in this way:

```
.hidden {
  right: -400px;
}
```

Don't repeat properties that are already present on the element ;)

Comment: thanks, i'm using the second method, works great and looks more realistic than working with the width. i've updated the codepen accordingly.